# Run nested batch files

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file

I'd like to run two batch files, which start a mongodb and a nodejs server.

In order to run the node-server I need to wait for mongodb to be executed.

I am so far, that I can run the mongodb like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process proc = null;
        try
        {
            string targetDir = string.Format(@"D:\nodejs\host");
            proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = targetDir;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "mongo.bat";
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception Occurred :{0},{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.ToString());
        }
    }
```

How can I execute the next batch file after mongo has finished initializing?

Comment: How about creating a new `Process` object after your `WaitForExit()` method? Your `string.Format` is useless by the way in your case.

Comment: That doesn't work. Mongodb needs some time to be initialized. Node-Server is starting too early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the tools involved so I can't give copy-pastable code, but I'd attempt to implement this flow (*very*-pseudo-code):

1. Create a Process to start MongoDB
2. Wait for a little while (I'd say 5 seconds)
3. Attempt to connect to MongoDB
4. If connection succeedes, GOTO 7
5. Wait a little while
6. GOTO 3
7. Create a Process to start node.js
8. Wait for a little while
9. Attempt to fetch some content from node.js
10. If fetch succeeds, GOTO 13
11. Wait for a little while
12. GOTO 9
13. Exit

The "wait" steps might happen on a different thread if you want to provide some feedback (I'm thinking for example a `BackgroundWorker` with timed `ProgressChanged` calls)

On second thought, this could apply to any combination of tools that start but aren't immediately available...

Answer (score 1):

You can use **WaitForExit()** like this.

```
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit(1000 * 60 * 5);    // wait for 5 minutes.
```

**OR**

```
proc = new Process();
while (!proc.HasExited)
{
    //mongoDB started
}
// Now start node server
```

Hope it helps you...

Comment: the mongo process isn't exiting, it stays opened. Isn't there a possibility to check if the process is waiting for input, or running idle .. sth. like that?

Comment: As Alex said try to connect to MongoDB to see if it is up and running.

Comment: Unfortunately the second process is starting too early, when mongodb hasn't finished initiliazing ..

Comment: Oh, I didn't see alex post. .. ;)